# How can I get variation purchase price by product id in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I get variation purchase price by product id in woocommerce?

I want to compare with sale total and purchase total
from api in another web page. but I tried to find the way to get from functions.php
I didn't found it. someone who know how to get variation purchase price by product id.
please show me how to get it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I meaned, Variation purchase price

Comment: Please edit your question with the information given above to make it more understandable by the audience.